# Design a 3-columns layout using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have to design a 3 columns layout with these conditions:

- I don't want to use percentages
- I don't care if left or right columns are made with pixels
- center column has to take the remaining width
- elements have to be aligned vertically
- I need the spans to be 100% height of their parent, to make the hover work with a full background-color

I tried using `display:flex` on the main container, it works well but I can't align the elements vertically. I tried using `display-table: cell` and `vertical-align: middle` but it doesn't seem to work with flex.

I developed a jsfiddle to show you what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/v13yy2v3/4/

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
#mainPercent {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    color: white;
}
#leftPercent {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    width: 5%;
    height:100%;
}
#centerPercent {
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
    /* percent isn't wanted */
    height:100%;
    display:table;
}
#centerPercent span {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align : middle;
}
#rightPercent {
    background-color: purple;
    float: right;
    height:100%;
    width: 5%;
}
#mainFlex {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    color: white;
    display:flex;
    /*   align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; items are not 100% height */
}
#leftFlex {
    background-color: green;
}
#centerFlex {
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    flex:1;
    /*display:table;*/
}
#rightFlex {
    background-color: purple;
}
#mainPx {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    color: white;
}
#leftPx {
    width:128px;
    float:left;
    background-color: green;
}
#centerPx {
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}
#rightPx {
    float:right;
    width : 128px;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<div id="mainPercent">
    <div id="leftPercent"><span>left</span>
    </div>
    <div id="centerPercent"><span>center</span>
    </div>
    <div id="rightPercent"><span>right</span>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="mainFlex">
    <div id="leftFlex"><span>left</span>
    </div>
    <div id="centerFlex"><span>center</span>
    </div>
    <div id="rightFlex"><span>right</span>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="mainPx">
    <div id="leftPx"><span>left</span>
    </div>
    <div id="centerPx"><span>center</span>
    </div>
    <div id="rightPx"><span>right</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It this the result you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/aj34h3yg/

Comment: It's perfect but I forgot to mention something. I need the spans to be 100% height of their parent, to make the hover work with a full background-color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to keep extending the flexbox to the child items and the spans.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#mainFlex {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.left {
  background-color: green;
}
.center {
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}
.right {
  background-color: purple;
}
.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
span {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 0.25em;
  flex: 1;
}
span:hover {
  background: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainFlex">
  <div class=" left child"><span>left</span>

  </div>
  <div class="center child"><span>center</span>

  </div>
  <div class="right child"><span>right</span>

  </div>
</div>
```